# Is there a way to detect a DOM-node change in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking for a way to detect if anything changes within a given DOM node. Is there an event or other technique that would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have something called DOM mutation events defined:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Currently this only works in Firefox, not on Internet Explorer.